# Not able to play Slo-Mo Videos with AVPlayer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! 
videoList_TableView_Cell_Controller
                let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
                let player = AVPlayer(url: cell.videoUrl!)
                playerController.player = player
    self.present(playerController, animated: true, completion: {
        playerController.player?.play()
    })
}
```

That is my  code for playing videos when user click on video icon from cell.But, problem is that when i want to play a Slo-Mo video that shows error. I am fetching video assets and then accessing them using urls. please provide a solution for slow motion videos.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rate` property of `AVPlayer` as show the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388846-rate)

> `var rate: Float`
>   The current playback rate.